# Rotate and autoscale a picture

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I want to rotate an image that is placed in a Grid cell:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="btnRotate" Click="btnRotate_Click">Rotate</Button>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Name="img" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

I tried two ideas:

- Using `RotateTransform` directly on the `Image` container. Unfortunately this transformation dismisses the properties `VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` of the container and the image exceeds cells borders.
- Using `RotateTransform` on a `TransformedBitmap` instance of the image. This construct rotates and autoscales perfectly, but the GC doesn't collect old instances; so it wastes much RAM capabilities.

This is the code behind for my second idea. If it wouldn't waste so much RAM, it will be fine.

```
private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bmp = new TransformedBitmap(bmp, new RotateTransform(90));
    bmp.Freeze();
    img.Source = bmp;
}
```

So, what is the best practice to rotate an image with autoscaling in its layout container?

Comment: Have you tried both RenderTransform and LayoutTransform?

Comment: I only used RenderTransform.

Comment: The RenderTransform gets applied after WPF already calculated all the sizes and measurements. LayoutTransform changes the object and afterwards calculates the size based on the changes. Should be worth a try.

Comment: @CShark that is the solution! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the LayoutTransform instead of the RenderTransform. The Transformations in the RenderTransform get applied after WPF already calculated all the sizes, positions and measurements for the individual objects, while Transformations in the LayoutTransform-group will be applied before WPF does all those calculations.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the image, the best way is to let WPF do the work and use LayoutTransform.

In XAML you have to add the Image.LayoutTranform Tag with the Rotation information:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="btnRotate" Click="btnRotate_Click">Rotate</Button>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Name="img" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

In C# you can now change the rotation in the click action:

```
    private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double rotation = (double)img.LayoutTransform.GetValue(RotateTransform.AngleProperty);
        rotation += 90;
        img.LayoutTransform.SetValue(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotation % 360);
    }
```